# Do I have to add a payment account with Stripe before I can change the Require Payments setting?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using the form so that parents know how much tuition and fees they have to pay, based on their requirements - essentially I am creating an invoice.  However, I don't want to actually process payments with Stripe. So, the option for them to "Pay Later" would be my option for payments.

All the help documents on the site show that I can change the "Require Payment" setting to Never, within the Payment Settings window. 
However, when I am in the Payment settings, that option is not available.

Am I missing something?

Do I have to add a payment account with Stripe before I can change the Require Payments setting?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing exactly what you need to do to make this work.  The Require Payment option is really Require Online Credit Card Payment.  If you do not connect your form to Stripe, it automatically treats all of your payment forms as invoices.

You can then select Include Receipt for confirmation emails to also include the receipt, which is really an invoice with an amount due like you would expect.